# CPU usage for each node in prometheus

Tags: cpu, prometheus, percentage, promql

Ideally I have to find out the CPU usage of pods on each node in percentage. But I have tried to find out the CPU usage of each node. I have written the query but it gives me more than 100 % (it can be 150% - 200%) even though the case with multiple cpus is included (I took avg). Could you please help me to understand what is wrong in the query below.

```
(1 - avg(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[1m])) by (instance)) * 100 / scalar(sum(machine_cpu_cores))
```

By reading multiple books and solutions I have found also the query that works only with several nodes (*container_spec_cpu_quota* isn't available for certain instances on AWS ECS)

```
avg(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name!~".*prometheus.*", image!="", instance=""}[1m])) by (pod) / scalar(sum(container_spec_cpu_quota{name!~".*prometheus.*", image!="", instance=""} / container_spec_cpu_period{name!~".*prometheus.*", image!="", instance=""}))
```

Comment: What is the value of "scalar(sum(machine_cpu_cores))"? How is "machine_cpu_cores" calculated?

Answer (score 7):

The following query returns the average CPU usage in percentage `[0 ... 100]%` per each node for the last 5 minutes:

```
100 * avg(1 - rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) by (instance)
```

This query assumes that a [node_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) runs per each monitored host and Prometheus is properly [configured](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs.html) for scraping all these node exporters.

The query works in the following way:

- The `rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle}[5m])` calculates per-second increase [rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) for idle CPU usage per each CPU core over the last 5 minutes (see `[5m]` in square brackets). This is basically the average number of seconds the given CPU core was idle per each second during the last 5 minutes. E.g. the value is in the range `[0 .. 1]`, where `0` means that the CPU core was 100% busy during the last 5 minutes, while `1` means that the CPU core was 100% idle during the last 5 minutes.
- The `1 - rate(...)` calculates CPU usage per each CPU core per each host.
- The `avg(...) by (instance)` calculates the [average](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg) CPU usage per each [instance](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/) (aka `host` in Prometheus ecosystem).
- The `100 * ...` multiplies the the average CPU usage per each host by 100 in order to get percentage on the range `[0 ... 100]%`.

Modern hosts usually have more than one CPU core. Sometimes the load among CPU cores may be uneven. For example, if an app, which can utilize only a single CPU core, runs on a host with 2 CPU cores, then CPU usage for this host will never exceed 50%, since the second CPU core is always idle, while the app cannot scale more. In these cases it may be useful to monitor the [maximum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg) CPU usage among available CPU cores per host:

```
100 * max(1 - rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) by (instance)
```

This query may help you identifying hosts with uneven CPU load, where some apps cannot scale to more CPU cores.

Comment: This rate is actually the average of the user, system etc. CPU usage rather than the sum of all the non-idle CPU usage.

Comment: @VictorWong, thanks for the pointer! I updated the answer to make it more useful

Answer (score 5):

The following query  return CPU usage per each node:

```
100 - (avg by(instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[2m])) * 100)
```