# Promql difference between max and max_over_time

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am very new to promql.
I want to know, what is the maximum cpu usage in last 7 days using promql for each instace. And figure out under utilized instance, by checking if its maximum cpu usage never crossed 20% in last 7 days.
I am not able to decide which of the below will give me desired result ?

```
max(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{service="x",mode!="idle"}[7d]) *100 ) by (instance)
```

and

```
max( max_over_time(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{service="x",mode!="idle"}[5m])[7d:])*100) by (instance)
```

Or there is any other better way to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

##### Difference between `max` and `max_over_time`

`max` returns maximum among time series returned by inner selector. Result is single time series.

`max_over_time` returns maximum value of every time series over specified range. Result contains number of values equal to number of inner time series.

Consider this [demo](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=node_cpu_seconds_total&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=max(node_cpu_seconds_total)&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h&g2.expr=max_over_time(node_cpu_seconds_total%5B1h%5D)&g2.tab=1&g2.stacked=0&g2.range_input=1h).

Same logic applies to all `<aggregation>` vs. `<aggregation>_over_time` functions.

##### Maximum CPU usage

> I want to know, what is the maximum CPU usage in last 7 days using promql for each instance.

First of all I'm assuming here you are using `node_exporter`'s metrics, and the following message will be based on this assumption, though I don't know what `service="x"` means in your selector. Hopefully it is just static label applied to target.

Regarding calculation of CPU utilization everything is not as simple as you tried.

I believe, simplest query to get CPU utilization of an instance is this:

```
100 - (avg by(instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[2m])) * 100)
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74128941/21363224).

So, to get maximum value over last week you could use this:

```
max_over_time((100 - (avg by(instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[2m])) * 100))[7d:])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I ran the query, interestingly i get no data on Prometheus console however graph shows the data .

Comment: @Laxmikant, what do you mean? This should work both in table and graph mode.

Comment: And as you mentioned it gives me range of values for each instance for 7 days... However I want just 1 maximum value per instance.. For example if  avg cpu usage of instance i1 gone max up to 65% in last 7 days .. the output should be {instance="i1"} and value=65

Comment: Last query from my answer should produce only one series per instance. And if you in table mode - one value: maximum over last 7 days. If you want to see only those, which over threshold, just add `>65` at the end of the query.