# PromQL if else logic

Tags: operators, prometheus, promql

I want to write a recording rule such that:

```
new_uptime = uptime if util <= 100 else uptime - (util - 100)
i.e Logic to record new_uptime metric is:
new_uptime = uptime when util less than or equal to 100,
new_uptime = uptime - (util - 100) when util is greater than 100
```

How do I use operators in correct way to achieve this?

Sorry a bit more context, I have attached screenshots for util and uptime

util:
[uptime metric sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Txn.png)

uptime:
[util metric sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTsWP.png)

Comment: Do `uptime` metric and `util` metric have same labels?

Comment: Yes, cluster and instance are same labels amongst the 2 metrics, I have also attached a screenshot of the 2 metrics

Comment: I doubt your uptime query does what you need. Check [the difference between `avg` and `avg_over_time`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76009728/21363224).

Comment: Also, right now, it only has label `cluster`, no instance it there. Have you missed it in the `by` clause? Also, your "util" query results have more labels. Is it guaranteed that (cluster, instance) pairs are unique?

Comment: Yup fixed the images, and yes it's always guaranteed that cluster, instance pairs are unique