# Prometheus node_exporter promql query to get aggregated daily peak (max) and avg CPU utilisation per node

Tags: prometheus, grafana, cpu-usage, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

What I need to obtain is a daily aggregation of the avg and max (peak) CPU utilisation per node/instance. So, the metric in question is:

```
node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!="idle"}
```

Exposed by `node_exporter`.

It's worth noting that I took a look at [Promql difference between max and max_over_time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76008051/promql-difference-between-max-and-max-over-time)
but this seems to relate to getting the max and avg across multiple time series, whereas I only need it on one.

My ultimate goal is to export the data as CSV from Grafana (Inspect->Data->Download CSV), however, if there's an easier way by using the Prometheus API directly, I'm happy to do that instead.

In case you're familiar with Oracle Enterprise Manager, the query made to generate the report there is:

```sql
select target_name, sum(average) CPU_AVE, sum(maximum) CPU_MAX, to_char(ROLLUP_TIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') TS_ROLLUP
      FROM SYSMAN.MGMT$METRIC_DAILY
      WHERE ROLLUP_TIMESTAMP > (sysdate -30) and target_name like 'servername'
        and (
                upper(COLUMN_LABEL) like upper('%CPU in User Mode%') or
                upper(COLUMN_LABEL) like upper('%CPU in System Mode %')
            )
    group by target_name,to_char(ROLLUP_TIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
   order by  TS_ROLLUP
;
```

Thanks in advance for any advice,

Comment: Your queries don't look right for described goal. Avg, as described in linked answer, calculates average among multiple tme series, not average of a single series over time. And `max_over_time` looks strange with `[$__rate_interval:]` (which is most likely something like two minutes) for declared desire of max over last 24 hours.

Comment: Additionally, since you are using grafana, why don't you simply enable legend with additional values for avg and max? Or are you only planning to show these two values without graph for counters usage over time?

Comment: Hi @markalex,
Thanks for your comments. `[$__rate_interval:]` was a typo, what I meant was `$__range`. However, even so, I'm still not getting the expected values. If you can recommend a query that would yield the expected result, I'd appreciate it.

As for Grafana legends, useful as they are, my ultimate goal is to export the data as CSV (Inspect->Data->Download CSV) so the legend is not useful for that particular purpose.